# Is Rosetta changing the theory of comets?

Tags: comets, space-probe

Rosetta is now arriving at Comet 67P.

Other comets have been analyzed to some degree (Giotto, Deep Space 1, Deep Impact, etc.)

So my question is... where I can study the up-to-date theory of comets? Much of what was previously thought (eg. dirty snowball) has been discarded now, but I haven't found a good source describing the current thinking.

Are there any firm predictions that will be tested as Rosetta studies the comet up close?

Comment: Looks like Planetary Society intends to post timely and informative updates on the comet http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2014/08150814-finding-my-way-around-cg.html as they do on other deep space probes.